# c# check IEnumerable for null

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am trying to check a type of `IEnuemrable<SystemUser>` for null.

I am using this piece of code

```
            var systemUsers = newActActivityPersons.SelectMany(x => x.Person.SystemUsers);
            if (systemUsers == null || !systemUsers.Any()) return ;
```

That isn't working. When I try to do something like `systemUsers.ToArray()` or  `systemUsers.ToList()` I get a null exception. How can I check this for errors?

Comment: it's not `systemUsers` that is null. what does the debugger say?

Comment: Your checking has no problem. Maybe newActActivityPersons is null.

Comment: SelectMany does not return null so that check is redundant anyway. if `systemUsers.ToList()` is throwing a NRE, it's being nulled afterwards. Post a bigger chunk that shows what's happening between here and where you're getting the exception.

Comment: Duplicate shows how to do *what you are asking about*. Note that your post is likely has nothing to do with problem you have and comment from @SaebAmini is likely explanation. Feel free to ask new question with [MCVE] if you still have the problem.

Comment: systemUsers is not null, therefore systemUsers.Any() is not executed, therefore you get an exception after when you try to enumerate because you have a null returned by x.Person before trying to access .SystemUsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the subsequent `x.Person.SystemUsers` could be null. `.Any()` returns true if there is one. If you then try to `ToList()` afterwards, you might find an `x` who's `Person` is null.

Check to make sure that `x.Person` isn't null before accessing a property on the object.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. It fixed the problem.